# "Preparing logs for uploading"

Tags: android, privacy

In my Android Studio catlog, I've noticed that these calls show up quite often:

> 11-09 09:19:19.671 19615-19631/? I/PlayCommon: [351] com.google.android.play.a.h.e(262): Preparing logs for uploading
>
> 11-09 09:19:19.681 19615-19631/? W/PlayCommon: [351] com.google.android.play.a.h.a(656): No account for auth token provided
>
> 11-09 09:19:19.682 19615-19631/? I/PlayCommon: [351] com.google.android.play.a.h.a(503): Connecting to server: https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
>
> 11-09 09:19:19.683 19615-19631/? E/PlayCommon: [351] com.google.android.play.a.h.a(533): Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname

This happens even when wifi is off. My concerns are privacy and performance (I noticed these calls before a freeze, which might or might not be related).

I would like to disable this automatic log sending to google. Ideally, stopping it altogether rather than blocking it with a firewall.

If it's not possible to do this from within my app, I'm also open to other ways of accomplishing it (rooting the device, etc).

Also, if someone could explain what these are and what they send, I would appreciate learning.

Thanks.

P.S. I'm on Marshmallow, in case that's useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

This might be simply diagnostic logs sent to Google or could be more concerning data.

To find out which, the packet stream would need to be captured.

Of course everything would be encrypted which makes the problem (aside from lack of transparency,  thanks do no evil Google) two fold of breaking the encryption just to determine the data sensitivity that is being transmitted to Google.